# Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_name()

Tags: php, freebsd

Пытался настроить исполнение скрипта cron.php при помощи crontab. Но при запуске cron.php выдает такую вот ошибку `Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_name()`. 
Версия php 5.3.29.

UPD: Пробовал поставить www/php5-session, не может для этой версии php установлена.

Comment: посмотрите вывод команды php -m на предмет наличия там строчки session

Comment: Есть там эта строчка.

Comment: @Михаил, В файле запущенном как cron нет понятия сессии т.к. файл открыт не браузере. Глубокая ошибка в понимании того как работает http протокол.

Comment: Ок, объяснение ваше понял.  Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При запуске php скрипта через crontab вы используете **php-cli** или иначе говоря запуск php **как консольное приложение** или просто скрипт системы.

Сессии это механизм сохранения данных пользователя работающего с сайтом через браузер используя например Куки или Session_id в GET части запроса. Соответственно при запуске скрипта в режиме php-cli никаких сессий быть не может и именно поэтому у вас выходит данная ошибка.